# How to integrate Genius api into my app?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a music app just like musixmatch and I want to show the lyrics of the songs. I want to integrate Genius api into my app so that I can fetch lyrics from their database. How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Genius API does not return lyrics but Musixmatch API returns.

Here is a sample in Android https://github.com/AlexeySAntonov/Musixmatch_lyrics_api_app

For more information about the API visit https://developer.musixmatch.com